# Meteor add active class (coffeescript)

Tags: jquery, meteor, coffeescript

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

```
<li class="alph-filter-button-unit" value="A">A</li>
<li class="alph-filter-button-unit" value="B">B</li>
<li class="alph-filter-button-unit" value="C">C</li>
<li class="alph-filter-button-unit" value="D">D</li>
```

Coffeescript:

```
  "click .alph-filter-button-unit":(e) ->
    $(e).addClass("filter-active")
```

I want to just add a class "filter-active" onto the "alph-filter-button-unit" that is clicked. There are no errors on the console either.

Comment: `$(e).addClass("filter-active")` to `$(this).addClass("filter-active")`

Answer (score 1):

```
"click .alph-filter-button-unit":(e)->
   $(e.currentTarget).addClass("filter-active")
```

To be more clear

```
Template.templateName.events
  "click .alph-filter-button-unit":(e)->
     $(".alph-filter-button-unit").removeClass("filter-active")
     $(e.currentTarget).addClass("filter-active")
```

Comment: Thanks, I kept adding the "currentTarget" part outside the brackets when I was trying it out. This fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The `e` param inside the event handler is the event object, not the clicked `dom` element so try

```
$(".alph-filter-button-unit").click (e) ->
    $(this).addClass("filter-active")
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kp0Lgtrn/)

Note: not an coffeescript expert so not sure about the handler registration part

Answer (score 0):

This line  $(e).addClass("filter-active") should become:

```
 $(e.target).addClass("filter-active")
```

or

```
 $(e.currentTarget).addClass("filter-active")
```